# Placing '0' and '1' character in C string

Tags: c, string

I've recently begun working with C again (haven't touched it since my first couple semesters of school) and have been dealing with strings.

Currently, I'm writing a function that will convert an integer into its binary representation in the form of a string.

Here is the code I have to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float power(int, int); //My version of the pow() function from math.h
char* itob(int);

int main ()
{
    int x = 63;

    const char * bin_x = itob(x);


    printf("x = %d (%s)",x,bin_x);

    return 0;
}

char* itob(int a){
    static char bin[100];

    int i;

    for(i=0;((int) power(2,i) < a);i++){
        bin[i] = (int)((a & ((int) power(2,i))) >> i);
    }

    bin[i] = '\0';

    return (char*)&bin;

}
```

The issue I'm having is that the result of the binary operations on *a* I'm storing into an element of *bin[]* seems to be '\001' or '\000' as opposed to simply '1' or '0'.  Because of this, when I printf() the result in main(), the output looks like a missing character box or if there is a 0 (if *x*=62 instead of 63) this is interpreted as an end of string character '\0'.

Am I storing these elements into my string incorrectly?

Comment: `bin[i] = (int)((a & ((int) power(2,i))) >> i);` will place either 1 or 0 into the array. That's not the same as the character `'1'` or `'0'`.

Comment: Also, why `return (char *)&bin;`? Why don't you simply `return bin;`?

Comment: @user3477950 Most likely because he tried `return &bin;` first, which is of type `char **`, and the compiler complained.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves it's not of type `char **`, it's of type `char (*)[100]`. But why would he return a pointer to array when he wants to return a pointer-to-`char`, in first place?

Comment: Also, @OP: in addition to the errors already discovered, you shan't be using `pow()` for this. It uses floating-point numbers which aren't reliable when you want to work with integers. Use bitwise shift operators instead.

Comment: @user3477950 Ops, I overlooked that. Indeed, it's a `char (*)[100]`. My guess is that his C is very rusty and at this point he has no idea what he's doing

Comment: If you are comfortable with bitwise operators, they are less expensive and less error prone to pull out the bits from an integer.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Fair enough, actually.

Comment: @user3477950 Because I tried several variations of that along with changing the declaration of bin to no avail, until that statement worked. Now I know a simple `return bin;` will suffice. Also good call with the left shift over `pow()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are storing it incorrectly. You are storing either a 0 or a 1, but you need to store its encoding instead.

Try to replace this line:

```
bin[i] = (int)((a & ((int) power(2,i))) >> i);
```

With:

```
bin[i] = (int)((a & ((int) power(2,i))) >> i) ? '1' : '0';
```

And you can simply `return bin;`, there is no need neither for the cast, nor for the use of the address of operator.

Answer (score 0):

**Do not** use `pow` for powers of 2, that's very inefficient, just a shift is enough. Your program wastes lots of time converting between `int` and `float`, and another tens of hundreds of cycles for the power while shifting generally takes only 1 cycle (or a little more depending on architecture). And no need to cast to `int`, any type shorter or equal to int will be automatically promoted to `int`

```
bin[i] = a & (1 << i) ? '1' : '0';    // or:
bin[i] = (a >> i) & 1 ? '1' : '0';
```

Much cleaner, shorter and faster. Another way if branching results in bad performance

```
bin[i] = ((a >> i) & 1) + '0';
```